# Make echo result clickable and run new query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, ajax, clickable

i have now searched the web for hours and i still cant figure it out.

So iam now asking you guys:

Okay, i have ha website, and a MS SQL server, (loalhost), and I want this function to work:

First: I run a query to print out all costumers in my database (in a table):`

```
$searchq = $_POST['search'];

   $resultArray = array();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Costumers WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$searchq."%' ";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
   if( $stmt == false){
       die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue) );
   }
```

Then I print the result in a table:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>CustomerID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Email</th><th>Productnr</th><th>Address</th></tr>";


    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 


{
    $resultArray[] = $row;

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

I have made an array list so that I can use the variable "row[x]" later in the code.. don't know if this is nessary but..

Second:
I now want this rows to be clickable, so if u click on a costumer from the table, you wil now run a new query:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Costumers =  '".$resultArray[0]['']."' ";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
   if( $stmt == false){
       die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue) );
   }
 echo "<table border='1'>";
 echo "<tr><th>CustomerID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Email</th><th>Productnr</th><th>Address</th></tr>";


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) 
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";



    }
        echo "</table>";
```

It should now print out all products that contains the same CosuterID as the one I clicked.

I have figured out that I need to use som AJAX, but I just can't get it to work.. Is here somone out there who can help me? I really need this to work!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set onClick function on td
Here also include Latest Jquery file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>CustomerID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Email</th><th>Productnr</th><th>Address</th></tr>";


    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 


{
    $resultArray[] = $row;

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td onClick='lodaproduct(" . $row[0] . ")'>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

//Set another row column to show the out put from ajax.php page 
echo "<tr><td id='costumersdata'></td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>

<script>
function lodaproduct(Costumers){
    $.post("ajax.php?Costumers="+Costumers, 
        function(data){
            $("#costumersdata").html(data);
    }); 
}
</script>
```

On your ajax.php page

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Costumers =  '".$_POST['Costumers']."' ";
   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
   if( $stmt == false){
       die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue) );
   }
 echo "<table border='1'>";
 echo "<tr><th>CustomerID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Tlf</th><th>Email</th><th>Productnr</th><th>Address</th></tr>";


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) 
    {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";



    }
 echo "</table>";       
?>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I only have 1 problem: it says : Notice: Undefined index: Costumers in ajax.php. any idea? 

Also wondering how to print the new table below the old one, and not inside CostumerID collum :D once again, thank you for your help!

Comment: I also see on ajax.php that I wrote this query: "SELECT * FRO; Products WHERE Costumers", it should say CostumerID, not Costumer, sorry about that..

Comment: Made it work, Needed to use $_GET in ajax.php instead of $_POST. And the print out was a easy fix, just adding a new table ofcourse.. You made my day Shaymol Bapary!

Answer (score 0):

I am putting a step by step instructions so you can follow this way:

1. Make a Column next which will be used to call AJAX on click method.
2. Pass the customer id to that AJAX function
3. AJAX call will send the customer id to specified controller
4. Controller / File will get the Customer ID and return the needed data in JSON.
5. The AJAX function get the returned JSON and populate it accordingly.